# WPF INotifyPropertyChanged two way binding strange action

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` as recommended by many threads.
**Implementation 1**

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string pName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
    }
}

public class Model : Notifier, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("name_changed"); }
    }
}
```

And the viewmodel consists of the model and command to make changes to model properties.

```
public class ViewModel : Notifier
{
    private Model _model;

    public Model Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { _model = value; OnPropertyChanged("model_changed"); }
    }

    private ICommand _cmd;

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return _cmd; }
        set { _cmd = value; }
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand(object para)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Command executed");
        Model.Name = "new name";
    }
}
```

VM is then binded to the view.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="100">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Model.Name" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule></ExceptionValidationRule>                
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

When the command is executed, the `TextBox` does not get updated to new value.
However, if I implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` like [this](https://intellitect.com/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/) instruction, the binding works. 
**Implementation 2**

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Model : Notifier, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
    }
}
```

What is missed in the first method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add property name like this.

```
public class Model : Notifier, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. So, the rule is "the parameter passed to the event must be identical to the property name". Always thought that it would be valid as long as it is unique string.

Comment: @M.Ko When you call `OnPropertyChanged("Name")` you're basically telling WPF that the property `Name` on `Model` has changed. So, it can't be any arbitrary string. As a side note, you can also do multiple OnPropertyChanges if the need arises. For example, if you have a GivenNames and LastName properties and a FullName property that is derived from GivenNames + LastName, you can have: `public LastName { set { name = value; OnPropertyChange("LastName"); OnPropertyChange("FullName") } }`

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with **Implementation 1** is that the string parameter of your `OnPropertyChanged` method needs to be the exact property name that is being changed. For your two examples, `"model_changed"` should be changed to `"Model"`
and `"name_changed"` should read `"Name"`. Here are two great techniques to mitigate potential human error with the typing of literal string names:

**1. Use the `CallerMemberName` Attribute**

If you are allowed and have access to the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace, you can write your base class as such to have the property name automatically passed as the string parameter of the `OnPropertyChanged` method:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string pName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call `OnPropertyChanged()` in your property's getter.

**2. Use the `nameof` keyword**

Alternatively, you may simply replace the literal typed property name with `nameof(<InsertPropertyNameHere>)` which will return the name without any risk of mistyping, like this example:

```
public class Model : Notifier, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name)); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Just noticed that. Most tutorials haven't mention that. I used the first method.